# Why did my Ocarina disappear?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask-3d

I had just got the boss key for the Ikana temple, but then I went back to Clock Town for some milk, but then I realized my ocarina was gone. I can no longer enter Ikana Valley because I need Epona to get in.

I tried restarting my game and when I go to my gear none of the 4 instruments are their. My ocarina also isn't appearing in the corner of the screen either.

Is this an intended event or a bug? Is there anything I can do to get my Ocarina back?

Answer (score 3):

The only time when you're supposed to lose your Ocarina, is at the beginning of the game when Skull Kid steals it. Therefore, it seems you've encountered a game-breaking bug.

If I were you, I'd see if I can reclaim the Ocarina from Skull Kid. Simply enter the Clock Tower on the last night and shoot Skull Kid (preferably with your Deku Mask). You can talk to the scarecrow at the observatory to pass time faster.

If that doesn't work, you might need to quit the game (press the Home button, close the game, start it again) or reload an earlier save where you still have your Ocarina.

If nothing works, I'm afraid you'll have no other choice but to restart your adventure. Without the Ocarina, you will be unable to:

- Reach and complete Stone Tower (Elegy of Emptiness)
- Call the giants on the last night (Oath to Order)
- Rewind time if you spent too much of it

Even if you manage to reach and complete Stone Tower in 3 days, the game will be unplayable without the Elegy of Emptiness and the Oath to Order, both of which require using the Ocarina of Time.

Comment: Hey thanks, navi was telling me to get the ocorina back from skull kid so I just did that quest again no I just have to hope I keep the boss key for the ikana temple.